# How to backfill the data from a csv into Prometheus maintaining the same timestamps in Go?

Tags: prometheus

Can I backfill data from csv to Prometheus maintaining the same timestamps as in the sample data in the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus doesn't support data ingestion in CSV, so you need to convert the data from CSV to the format supported by Prometheus for data ingestion. See [this article](https://grafana.com/blog/2020/09/02/how-were-improving-backfill-methods-to-get-older-data-into-prometheus/) for details.

Another solution is to import CSV data to Prometheus-compatible system such as VictoriaMetrics. See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-import-csv-data).